# @ApplicationScoped Bean Not Eagerly Instantiated on Wildfly 16

Tags: jboss, wildfly, cdi

I have an @ApplicationScoped bean that I want to be instantiated on application startup (see sample code below). I've registered for the servlet context initialization event but the init method is never invoked. The FactoryLocator is contained in a jar within my war's WEB-INF/lib directory. This same code was working on Wildfly 9 but no longer works after upgrading to Wildfly 16.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Initialized;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

@ApplicationScoped
public class FactoryLocator {
    public FactoryLocator() {
        System.out.println("In the constructor.........................");
    }

    private void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext sc) {
        System.out.println("Invoking the event observer method..................");
        }
}
```

One workaround I discovered was to extract the contents of the jars in my war's WEB-INF/lib/ directory to my war's WEB-INF/classes directory. When I did this my FactorLocator bean was instantiated successfully. I'd prefer not to have to do this.

After debugging through the war's deployment, I noticed that the ServletContext is initialized before all the beans in the war's lib directory are processed (org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeploymentModules:processBeanDeployments). The war's module is not aware of all observers until all the beans are processed. However, the ServletContextEvent is fired before all the observers are known.

Should this happen that ServletContext is created before all observers are known about? I've debugged one of the Wildfly QuickStart applications and the ServletContext isn't created until all bean deployments are processed and the code below is executed successfully. Is the order in which this happens supposed to be guaranteed?

Comment: The beans are discovered but the issue seems to be due to the fact the ServletContextEvent is emitted before the beans are processed and the observer methods are discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has seen the same issue. Upgrading to Wildfly 21.0.1.Final resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Have the same issue wildfly 25. Any idea?